# Deploying java web application on cloud

Tags: java, web-hosting, cloud-hosting, domain-name

I have read about Amazon web service (aws), openshift for deploying java web application.But like openshift the public URL consist of "**rhccloud.com**".

But I want only my domain name in the url like www.domain-name.com
Can someone guide me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a purchased a domain name you can set it for your Openshift app via `rhc` utility like this:

```
rhc alias add {appName} {alias}
```

See more [here](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202301854-How-can-I-set-up-my-own-domain-name-to-point-to-my-app-)